# silverlight bug?

Tags: silverlight

I need your help!

I have some usercontrol in which hovering mouse on this keyword threw an strange error

```
class Puzzle : UserControl {

 public void Animate()
 {
        this.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, 0.0); // expression has been evaluated and has no value

  }   
}
```

what is wrong with this approach?

Comment: which error do you have exactly ?

Comment: "this keyword"? What keyword? do mean the `this` keyword.

Comment: I don't have any errors or exception

Comment: when I debug this code in visual studio and try to add to watch this.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, 0.0) I get a message from debugger "expression has been evaluated and has no value'

Comment: Problem is that my Puzzle control position on screen is incorrect(((

Answer (score 1):

From your followup comment, you are trying to watch a [method call on a method that has a void return type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597473%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

The debugger is trying to be helpful by telling you it has no value.

Try adding a watch on the matching GetValue method instead :)

Comment: That is the problem!Debugger says that everything fine but position of my Puzzle object is incorrect!

Comment: I mean when I execute puzzle.Animate() my puzzle position set to 0 but on the screen I don't see it actually at 0!!!!!:(

Comment: @magic987: Can you provide the XAML of your page? The dependancy property Canvas.TopProperty only works if the immediate parent object is a canvas. Otherwise it is just ignored.

Comment: parent object is canvas.However apply MouseElementDragBehavior to each my Puzzle control and it looks like this behaviour doing something bad with my control..